# Passing an object back to MainWindow from a subwindow

Tags: c#, wpf, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to create a little database program in which you can add, modify and remove articles for a news site. There is a MainWindow with a DataGrid to display all the articles. Once the Add button is pressed, a new window opens to let you edit the newly created article. Or the modify button can be pressed to edit the currently selected article. How can i pass the article back to the MainWindow to add it to the ObservableCollection/modify the ObservableCollection?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private int lastIdArtikel = 0;
        private Artikel currentSelection = null; 
        private ObservableCollection<Artikel> ArtikelDatabase = new ObservableCollection<Artikel>();

        private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Artikel nieuwArtikel = new Artikel(++lastIdArtikels);
            ArtikelDatabase.Add(nieuwArtikel);
            ArtikelVenster artikelVenster = new ArtikelVenster(ref nieuwArtikel);
            artikelVenster.Show();
        }

        private void Modify_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ArtikelVenster artikelVenster = new ArtikelVenster(ref huidigeSelectie);
                artikelVenster.Show();
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.StackTrace);
            }            
        }
```

```
 public partial class ArtikelVenster : Window
    {
        public Artikel artikel { get; private set; }
        public int id { get; private set; }
        public string title { get; private set; }
        public object category { get; private set; }
        public string nameJournalist { get; private set; }
        public bool mayBePublished { get; private set; }
        public bool isPublished { get; private set; }
        public string content { get; private set; }
        public int length { get; private set; }

        public ArtikelVenster(ref Artikel huidigArtikel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            artikel = huidigArtikel;
            try
            {
                LaadData();
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.StackTrace);
            }
            CategorieBox.SelectedIndex = 2;
        }

        private void Cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void LaadData()
        {
            IdLabel.Content = artikel.id;
            DatumLabel.Content = artikel.creationDate.ToString();
            TitelBox.Text = artikel.title;
            CategorieBox.SelectedItem = artikel.category;
            NaamJournalistBox.Text = artikel.nameJournalist;
            IsGepubliceerdToggle.IsChecked = artikel.isPublished;
            MagGepubliceerdWordenToggle.IsChecked = artikel.mayBePublished;
            if (artikel.content == null)
            {
                InhoudBox.Selection.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                InhoudBox.Selection.Text = artikel.content;
            }
        }

        private void Confirm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (artikel == null)
            {
                Artikel nieuwArtikel = new Artikel(id);
                nieuwArtikel.updateArtikel(title, category, nameJournalist, mayBePublished, isPublished, content, length);
                artikel = nieuwArtikel;
            }
            else
            {
                artikel.updateArtikel(title, category, nameJournalist, mayBePublished, isPublished, content, length);
            }
            this.Close();
        }

        private void TitelBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            title = TitelBox.Text;
        }

        private void CategorieBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            category = CategorieBox.SelectedItem;
        }

        private void NaamJournalistBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            nameJournalist = NaamJournalistBox.Text;
        }
    }
```

```
    public class Artikel
    {
        public int id { get; private set; }
        public string title { get; private set; }
        public object category { get; private set; }
        public string nameJournalist { get; private set; }
        public bool mayBePublished { get; private set; }
        public bool isPublished { get; private set; }
        public string content { get; private set; }
        public int length { get; private set; }
        public DateTime creationDate { get; private set; }

        public Artikel(int id)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.creationDate = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public void updateArtikel(string title, object category, string nameJournalist, bool mayBePublished, bool isPublished, string content, int length)
        {
            this.title = title;
            this.category = category;
            this.nameJournalist = nameJournalist;
            this.mayBePublished = mayBePublished;
            this.isPublished = isPublished;
            this.content = content;
            this.length = length;
        }
    }
}
```

Some parts are left out to make it more readable. If anymore info is needed, let me know.

Comment: By making a public property in your ArtikelVenster class that would carry the result object reference and then accessing it from the caller

Comment: @yassinMi there is already a public Artikel property, but i need some kind of event when the ArtikelVenster is closing/when a button is pressed to let the MainWindow know to add the Artikel to the ObservableCollection. Sorry if this wasn't completely clear.

Comment: Only when the confirm button is clicked can i be sure that all the fields are entered and the Artikel may be added to the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare an event in your window class

```
public event EventHandler<Artikel> Confirmed;
```

Invoke it in the confirm button click handler

```
//artikel being the object that you want to send back to the main window  
 
Confirmed?.Invoke(this,artikel);
```

You can add listener from the caller :

```
artikelVenster.Confirmed+=(s, e) =>{//do something with e };
artikelVenster.Show();
```

Comment: As-is, this would require Artikel to inherit EventArgs, which probably isn't a good idea. Better to make a dedicated ArtikelEventArgs that encapsulates the Artikel reference. Still, the overall approach looks good to me: +1!

Comment: Is that a constraint in the framwork itself or just a better way of doing it? Because I don't get any compile or run time errors / warnings when I use any type

Comment: Ah, you're right there is no generic constraint to force `TEventArgs` to inherit `System.EventArgs` - but yeah it's totally a best practice: that way if/when the handler needs any additional information the type of the event and the signature of its handlers doesn't need to change, just add new members to the EventArgs-derived class and you're done.